# Sorting technique C

Tags: c

I am into programming from past 7-8 months and I generally use selection sort whenever I want to sort arrays or structures. So I got idea and implemented it. selection sort find max OR min value in each loop and place it at one of the border (depends on max or min) and make it out of scope. So I thought why not find max AND min in each loop and move them to borders (min-left and max-right) and reduce the scope from both side by value 1. It would have half of previous time complexity i guess. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int *a;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = malloc (n * sizeof (int));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    int start = 0, end = n;

    int temp;
    while (start < end){
        int max_index;
        int min_index;

        int max_num = INT_MIN, min_num = INT_MAX;

        for (int i = start; start != end && i < end; i++){
            if (a[i] > max_num){
                max_num = a[i];
                max_index = i;
            }
            if (a[i] < min_num)  {
                min_num = a[i];
                min_index = i;
            }
        }

        if ((max_index == start && min_index == end - 1) || (max_index == end - 1 && min_index == start)){  
            temp = a[end - 1];      //if max and min numbers are at border they will swap two times resulting in same location
            a[end - 1] = a[max_index];
            a[max_index] = temp;
        } else {
            temp = a[end - 1];
            a[end - 1] = a[max_index];
            a[max_index] = temp;

            temp = a[start];
            a[start] = a[min_index];
            a[min_index] = temp;
        }

        start++;
        end--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

I tested it with 600 int values, Here is the [Output](https://pastebin.com/KSycLvpx). It seems to work fine. Is it better than  selection sort or just same. I guess qsort would be be superior to both in terms of speed and efficiency. I looked for it on google and didn't found similar code to this which make me wonder, Is this efficient enough or should I stick with selection sort and qsort.

Comment: This algorithm looks like O(n^2) because the inner loop starts from the full range and the range is decreased by 2 per one iteration of outer loop.

Comment: This is called "double selection sort" or "cocktail sort" on [the wikipedia article about selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Variants). It's in O(n^2), just as selection sort, and thus scales significantly worse than `qsort`.

Comment: At best this will be an O(n**2) algorithm, while good sorting algorithms are O(n*log(n)).  You should just use the library function `qsort`.  That will be faster than what you're attempting.

Comment: It is definitely better than raw Selection sort. That being said, there is probably not a worse algorithm for sorting than Selection sort. Even utter trash like the Bubble sort is solid in quasi-preordered-array cases. If you're looking to improve your coding skills, ditch selection sort as soon as possible.

Comment: If you want to learn an O(n*log(n)) sorting algorithm, look at quicksort, merge sort, or heapsort.  They're all pretty easy to implement, and for large lists any of them will be faster than what you're trying to do.

Comment: I mostly use qsort but I find it difficult to use with structures, so I go back to selection sort. With more practice, I would be able to ditch selection sort. Wirting cmp func always get me :(

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara You basically have two choices:  You can write a new custom sort function each time you want to sort a new data type, or you can learn to write `cmp` functions so that you can use a fast, reliable library function to do your sorting.

Comment: *I generally use selection sort whenever I want to sort arrays or structure* Is there any problem with the C library's `qsort` routine? You should use it unless you can articulate a reason why it's insufficient :)

Comment: Sometime I can write cmp func and it works fine. What I know is I should subract variable on which I want structure to be sorted and return the diffrence. But when I am working with double pointers and struct like last day it all get messed up

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara No, you don't need to use subtraction at all.  Your cmp function just needs to return negative, zero, or positive.  For example, you could always return one of -1, 0, or 1.  Things like `strcmp` use subtraction as a fast way to obtain the three-way comparison value when comparing two characters, but there is no reason why they have to.

Comment: I genrally skip return as substration saves lines and if else, but if diffrence is between -1 and 1 it will return 0 which will mess the result. It came to my mind just now and it could be reason why I messed it up. I would better stick with return statements. Thanks @TomKarzes

Comment: If you really want to sort an array in-place using explicitly written code (rather than using the standard library `qsort`), I think _heapsort_ is a good choice because the amount of required code is quite small, it needs hardly any auxiliary storage O(1), and its worst-case time efficiency is O(n log n).

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara The differerence between -1 and 1 is -2, which is consistent with the fact that -1 < 1 (i.e., -2 is negative).  But as I said, subtraction only makes sense when it's convenient, and more importantly, when you know it won't overflow.  If you're comparing something more complex, it's often easiest to have fixed return values of -1, 0, and 1.

Comment: @TomKarzes I meant if diffrence is 0.5 or -0.5 it will become 0 while it should have return value greater or less than 0 not zero.

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara Right, so in that case you'd skip the subtraction and do something like `return a < b ? -1 : a > b : 1 : 0;`  And with floating point or integers, in general you can't safely subtract without risking overflow, so subtracting is mostly only useful for `char` and possibly `short` values.  Consider it the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Thanks for the all the help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm implements a variant of selection sort called Cocktail Sort or Shaker Sort. It is not significantly faster than selection sort because it uses a similar amount of comparisons, thus has a time complexity of **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** just like selection sort.

There are problems in your implementation:

- Your code does not compile on some platforms because you forgot to include the header file **<limits.h>** where `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are defined.
- Your implementation has undefined behavior if the data set contains only the value `MIN_INT` or `MAX_INT` because you would then fail to find the smallest or largest element of the slice and `min_index` and/or `max_index` would have indeterminate values thus leading to undefined behavior when dereferencing `a[max_index]` or `a[min_index]`.
- You swap the values if `(max_index == end - 1 && min_index == start)`, causing an incorrect result: the values should be left alone in this case.
- Another special case must be handled explicitly: if `min_index == end - 1` then you must swap the min value first as it would be moved when you set the max value in place.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int status = 0;
    int *a;
    for (int n = 1; n < 100000; n += n / 3 + 1) {
        a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = rand();
        clock_t t = clock();
        for (int start = 0, end = n - 1; start < end; start++, end--) {
            int max_index = start;
            int min_index = start;
            int max_num = a[max_index];
            int min_num = a[min_index];
            int temp;

            for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
                if (max_num < a[i])
                    max_num = a[max_index = i];
                if (min_num > a[i])
                    min_num = a[min_index = i];
            }
            if (min_index == end) {
                if (max_index == start) {
                    /* single swap needed */
                    temp = a[end];
                    a[end] = a[start];
                    a[start] = temp;
                    continue;
                }
                /* first swap the smallest value at the first position */
                temp = a[start];
                a[start] = a[min_index];
                a[min_index] = temp;
                /* then swap the largest value at the last position */
                temp = a[end];
                a[end] = a[max_index];
                a[max_index] = temp;
            } else {
                /* first swap the largest value at the last position */
                temp = a[end];
                a[end] = a[max_index];
                a[max_index] = temp;
                /* then swap the smallest value at the first position */
                temp = a[start];
                a[start] = a[min_index];
                a[min_index] = temp;
            }
        }
        t = clock() - t;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i-1] > a[i]) {
                printf("sorting error n=%d, a[%d] = %d > %d = a[%d]\n",
                       n, i-1, a[i-1], a[i], i);
                status = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        free(a);
        printf("n=%d: %.3fms\n", n, t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: max_num = a[max_index = i]; is this equivalent to max_num = a[i]; max_index = i;

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara: yes. More precisely, it is equivalent to `max_index = i, max_num = a[max_index];`

Answer (score 5):

> It would have half of previous time complexity i guess.

O(0.5 * n^2) is still O(n^2).  A good `qsort()` is expected O(n* ln(n)).

> Is this efficient enough or should I stick with selection sort and qsort.

Tough to beat decades of many programmers experience.

Keep in mind `qsort()` does not have to use  the *quick sort* algorithm.  A good `qsort()` may use a combination of algorithms.

Comment: [GNU C Library - qsort()](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html) uses a combination of of quicksort and then finishes with an insertion sort leveraging the best of both techniques for a very efficient sort algorithm. The Mac qsort from apple is almost identical.